# Need help manipulating files in C, how can I read more than one line in a function at a time?

Tags: c

### sorry for any mistakes, my native language is not english.
I need help with my code:

```
// Esse programa lê dados de um arquivo TXT, contendo nome, altura e peso
// entao ele retorna esses mesmos dados, alem de informar o IMC da pessoa que esta nos dados
// informando tambem se é obesa ou magra etc.
// Raphael Azambuja Silva Macedo 2020

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Estruturas
typedef struct // Struct das pessoas
{
    char nome[100];
    int peso;
    float altura;
} pessoa;

// Prototipos
float imc(int peso, float altura);
void showIMC(float imcalculado);
void showP(char nome[100], int peso, float altura);
void mIMC(char nome1[100], char nome2[100], int peso1, int peso2, float altura1, float altura2);
pessoa getP(char fns[100]);

// Variaveis externas
const int MAXFN = 50;


int
main()
{
    int i=0; // Contador
    int n,m; // Valor da struct das pessoas comparadas
    char fn[MAXFN]; // Nome do arquivo
    float valorimc; // valor do IMC
    FILE *file = NULL; // Ponteiro que abre o arquivo

    printf("\nDigite o nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s", fn);
    file = fopen(fn, "r");

    if (file == NULL) // Checagem para ver se o arquivo abriu corretamente
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ARQUIVO NAO PODE SER ABERTO");
        return 0;
    }
    pessoa z[4]; // Variavel Z da struct pessoa
    for (i = 0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        z[i] = getP(fn);
        valorimc = imc(z[i].peso,z[i].altura); // Chamando a função que calcula o resultado
        showP(z[i].nome,z[i].peso,z[i].altura); // Chamando a função que mostra os dados
        showIMC(valorimc); // Chamando a função que calcula e mostra o IMC
    }
    printf("\n=================\n");
    printf ("\n\nDigite a enumeracao das pessoas que quer comparar o IMC, sendo a primeira ''0''\n");
    scanf(" %d",&n);
    scanf(" %d",&m);
    mIMC(z[n].nome,z[m].nome,z[n].peso,z[m].peso,z[n].altura, z[i].altura);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

float // Função que calcula o IMC
imc(int peso, float altura)
{
    float resultado;
    resultado = peso / (altura*altura);
    return resultado;
}

void
showIMC(float imcalculado) // Função que mostra os dados do IMC
{
    printf("O IMC dessa pessoa eh: %f" ,imcalculado);

    if (imcalculado <= 18.5)
    {
        printf("\nMagreza");
    }
    else if (imcalculado > 18.5 && imcalculado <= 24.9)
    {
        printf("\nPeso normal");
    }
       else if (imcalculado > 24.9 && imcalculado <= 30)
    {
        printf("\nSobrepeso");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nObesidade");
    }
}

void
showP(char nome[100], int peso, float altura) // Função que mostra os dados da pessoa
{
    printf("\n=================\n");
    printf("Nome da pessoa: %s\nPeso da pessoa: %d\nAltura da Pessoa: %f\n",nome,peso,altura);
}


void // Função que compara ambos IMC
mIMC(char nome1[100], char nome2[100], int peso1, int peso2, float altura1, float altura2)
{
    int IMC1,IMC2; // IMC de cada Pessoa
    IMC1= peso1 / (altura1*altura1);
    IMC2= peso2 / (altura2*altura2);
    if (IMC1>IMC2)
    {
        printf("\n=====================\n");
        printf("A pessoa %s tem o menor IMC." ,nome2);
    }
    else if (IMC2>IMC1)
    {
        printf("\n=====================\n");
        printf("A pessoa %s tem o menor IMC." ,nome1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n=====================\n");
        printf("As duas pessoas tem o mesmo IMC.");
    }
}

pessoa getP(char fns[100])
{
    pessoa t;
    FILE *file = fopen(fns, "r");
    fscanf (file, " %[^0123456789] %d %f" ,t.nome,&t.peso,&t.altura);
    return t;
}
```

What I need to do is:
Every time I call the ''getP'' function I need to read a diferent line of info from the txt file, however, every time the function is called it starts reading from the beginning, so I always get the first line.

The txt file is:

```
beltano das couves 90 1.7
fulano de tal 80 1.7
sicrano de tel 75 1.7
deltrano de tol 70 1.7
```

Comment: Don't open the file more than once. Every time you open the file, it starts at the beginning.  Consider asking your questions in your own language on [pt.so].

Comment: Oh thanks! Didnt know we had one haha.

Comment: You might be able to use `getline()`, and save yourself some work.